# In Numbers 30:8 and Numbers 30:15 why does annulling vows seem to have different consequences?

Tags: law, numbers

Numbers 30:8 and Numbers 30:12 states that the woman in question who makes the vow will Not be held against her if her husband annuls said vow.
Numbers 30:15 states that the husband will bear the guilt of the woman who makes a vow if the aforementioned husband annuls her vows.

> Numbers 30 New American Standard Bible (NASB) The Law of Vows
>
> 30 Then Moses spoke to the heads of the tribes of the sons of Israel, saying, “This is the word which the Lord has commanded. 2 If a man makes a vow to the Lord, or takes an oath to bind himself with a binding obligation, he shall not violate his word; he shall do according to all that proceeds out of his mouth. 
>   ...
>
> 6 “However, if she should [b]marry while [c]under her vows or the rash statement of her lips by which she has bound herself, 7 and her husband hears of it and says nothing to her on the day he hears it, then her vows shall stand and her obligations by which she has bound herself shall stand. **8 But if on the day her husband hears of it, he forbids her, then he shall annul her vow which [d]she is under and the rash statement of her lips by which she has bound herself; and the Lord will forgive her.**
>
> 9 “But the vow of a widow or of a divorced woman, everything by which she has bound herself, shall stand against her. 10 However, if she vowed in her husband’s house, or bound herself by an obligation with an oath, 11 and her husband heard it, but said nothing to her and did not forbid her, then all her vows shall stand and every obligation by which she bound herself shall stand. **12 But if her husband indeed annuls them on the day he hears them, then whatever proceeds out of her lips concerning her vows or concerning the obligation of herself shall not stand; her husband has annulled them, and the Lord will forgive her.**
>
> 13 “Every vow and every binding oath to humble herself, her husband may confirm it or her husband may annul it. 14 But if her husband indeed says nothing to her from day to day, then he confirms all her vows or all her obligations which are on her; he has confirmed them, because he said nothing to her on the day he heard them. **15 But if he indeed annuls them after he has heard them, then he shall bear her guilt.”**
>
> 16 These are the statutes which the Lord commanded Moses, as between a man and his wife, and as between a father and his daughter, while she is in her youth in her father’s house.

Numbers 30:8 and Numbers 30:12 states that the woman in question who makes the vow will Not be held against her if her husband annuls said vow.
Numbers 30:15 states that the husband will bear the guilt of the woman who makes a vow if the aforementioned husband annuls her vows.

If you click on the following link then you will see different bible translations side-by-side for the aforementioned verses in order to see if you can get a broader understanding.

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers%2030&version=NASB;NKJV;AMP;NIV

Why does Numbers 30:8 and Numbers 30:12 have a more conciliatory approach compared to Numbers 30:15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases here:

1. After the husband hears her vow, he has a day to annul it. If he annuls it, the vow is no longer binding.
2. But if he hears the vow and is silent for an entire day, he implicitly accepts the vow as binding and no longer has the right to annul it, and therefore he bears her guilt if he annuls the vow after that point in time.

The first two verses are instances of the first case, where the vow is annulled on the same day:

> But if **on the day her husband hears of it, he forbids her**, then he shall annul her vow which she is under and the rash statement of her lips by which she has bound herself; and *the Lord will forgive her*. (v. 8)
>
> But if her husband indeed **annuls them on the day he hears them**, then whatever proceeds out of her lips concerning her vows or concerning the obligation of herself shall not stand; her husband has annulled them, and *the Lord will forgive her*. (v. 12)

Verses 14-15 deal with the second case, where the husband is silent for a day after having heard the vow.

> But if her husband indeed says nothing to her from day to day, then he confirms all her vows or all her obligations which are on her; he has confirmed them, because **he said nothing to her on the day he heard them**. But if he indeed annuls them after he has heard them, then *he shall bear her guilt*. (v. 14-15)